# winforms switch between tabs while current one is busy doing processing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

i have winform (c#) with multi-tabs, the current focused tab is busy doing lengthy Async operation and embedded progressbasr "in that tab" showing the progress. i want to let the user be able to navigate to other tabs and perform other tasks in case he/she don't wanna wait. so how i can do that in simple and robust way?

this is the lengthy op in short:

```
foreach (DataRow _dr in _allDt.Rows)
{
   //check if machine is online out of 100 machines list using async approach
        if (_connectionUtil.ConnectionIsOn(_dr["ipAddress"].ToString()))
            _onMachineAl.Add(_machineInfo);
    _progressBar.PerformStep();

 }
```

do i have to use thread?! or simpler way available? please provide code-segment or helpful source.

EDIT:

```
//async part:
 using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                IAsyncResult result = tcpClient.BeginConnect(ipAddress, 3306, null, null);
                WaitHandle timeoutHandler = result.AsyncWaitHandle;
```

thanks,

Comment: I don't really understand the question.....?  If you're doing things asynchronously already, aren't you already using threads?

Comment: Asynchronously it wont happen for that can you provide some more information?

Comment: @jadook -- Just because you are using the async methods on TcpClient, doesn't mean that your loop is async. In addition to that, it appears as if you are using the async method and then blocking until it returns, so your `ConnectionIsOn()` method can return true/false.

Comment: @Nate yes i gotta wait to get bool value: if (!result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(waitTimeSpan, false)) but waitOn is also async!. in case i can use tcpClient in better way that would solve the problem automatically please advise. thanks,

Comment: @Nate: i'm using same code for tcpClient in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583873/c-how-to-set-test-tcp-connection-timeout/4584514#4584514

Comment: @Nate: i saw typo in your SO info section: [Engoy]

Comment: @jadook, as soon as you block, any async operations are wasted (in terms of UI response). If you implement my solution, the way you've written your ConnectionIsOn will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already performing your task asynchronously, then the user should already be able to switch between tabs because the async operations will not be blocking the UI thread.

If you are not really doing your task asynchronously the user will not be able to do much of anything because you are blocking the UI thread.

That being said, I suspect you are in the second camp, so something like this should help you get going:

```
var mi = new MethodInvoker(() =>
{
    foreach(dataRow _dr in _allDt.Rows)
    {
        if(_connectionUtil.ConnectionIsOn(_dr["ipAddress"].ToString()))
            _onMachineAl.Add(_machineInfo);
        this._progressBar.Invoke(() => { _progressBar.PerformStep(); });
    }
});
mi.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

Comment: i test your code and i could switch between tabs but i couldn't see the results in UI after the operation finished. inside the actual code i got more lines after the mi.BeginInvoke how should i handle that code? and what about the resources! after the mi work done is it auto destroyed?

Comment: Also, one last question: how to show msgBox after the operation finished. do i have to do something special or just normal way. and where to put that line after or before the beginInvoke..?

Comment: You need to define a callback method, and provide it in the `mi.BeginInvoke()` call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your 'long-time' operation in separate thread or background worker. In this case UI will be free and user can continue work with application. But do not forget to notify user when operation is complete.

Here is the sample:

```
new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate() 
    {
        foreach (DataRow _dr in _allDt.Rows)
        {
            //check if machine is online out of 100 machines list using async approach
            if (_connectionUtil.ConnectionIsOn(_dr["ipAddress"].ToString()))
                _onMachineAl.Add(_machineInfo);

            this._progressBar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() // Invoke you need for accessing the UI thread and controls
            { 
                _progressBar.PerformStep();
            }));

        }
    })).Start();
```

Comment: i don't understand the invoke part, why its linked to the progressBar! PB is part of same busy-tab. can you explain more please. thanks

Comment: i found the answer regarding invoke in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319509/c-communication-between-async-networking-and-gui

Comment: Because you are in separate thread you need to communicate with the UI thread. Invoke: _Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle._ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx